# MSMQ : Is there any option to convert existing Express messages stored to recoverable?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I have a situation where i can't write objects to disk frequently in my C# app  . So i am implementing a system where i write objects to the MSMQ as Express Messages which is to be consumed by other application. If messages are not consumed for say 15 minutes, i have to persist that messages to disk .

I have read that we can persist MSMQ Messages to disk if we set recoverable to true for each message before putting in the queue.

Is there any option to make already stored Express messages to Recoverable messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not - the messages are stored on disk but if the msmq queuing service restarts they will be deleted.